# Future list and refresh loaders | Flutter problem

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am fetching data from a database and want to implement refresh loader on the same screen and same list. But refresh loader takes a list and I have tried to implement refresh loader with the future list but no success.

Comment: could you add the code you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess u want that:

```
RefreshIndicator(
   child: _futureBuilder(),
   onRefresh: () => _refresh(),
),
```

The _futureBuilder() is a normal future builder. Try the refresh indicator!